# Add a note on the left, next to a line of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to add on the right to the 1 a small note `<- i-th line`. How to do it ?

[image]

My solution so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\epsilon_i = 
\left (
\begin{array}{c}
\vdots \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right ) \text{\small $\gets$ $i$-ième ligne}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead say i'th column of the identity matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ti*k*z' `tikzmark` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[ \epsilon_i = 
    \left (
        \begin{array}{c}
            \vdots \\
            0 \tikzmark{lineOne}\\
            1 \tikzmark{lineTwo}\\
            0 \\
            \vdots
        \end{array}
    \right )
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=west] at ($(pic cs:lineOne)+(.4,.1)$) {\small $\gets (i-1)$-th line};
\node[anchor=west,red] at ($(pic cs:lineTwo)+(.4,.13)$) {\small $\gets i$-th line};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]